# Multiple constrain to fmincon? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm not sure that `fmincon` is the best solution for optimization with multiple parameters.

I want to optimize two parameters: `inp_1` with allowed values between `1` and `2` for which I used this code

```
inp_1 = 1
Ub= 2*inp_1 ; Lb= 0.5*inp_1;
options = optimoptions('fmincon',...
         'FiniteDifferenceType','central',...
         'DiffMaxChange',0.5,...
         'DiffMinChange',1e-1,...
         'MaxIter',20,...
         'MaxFunEvals',200,...
         'Display','iter',...  % 'iter'
         'OptimalityTolerance',1e-13);
[param,distance,exitflag,output,lambda,grad,hessian]  = fmincon(@optimization_func,inp_1 ,[],[],[],[],[],Lb,Ub,options);
```

and everything works fine. If I want to add another dependecy, like `inp_2` with allowed values between `0` to `360`, I can set a vector `x` as `x(1) = inp_1;` and `x(2) = inp_2` and pass `x` to fmincon.

In this way options are not correct anymore, since I need to set other options, especially for `DiffMinChange` and `DiffMaxChange`. Which is the best solution here for multiple-different constrains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the options `DiffMinChange` and `DiffMaxChange` always apply to the whole vector and cannot be tuned per-element.

What you could do is normalize all your variables to be in the unit `[0,1]` interval so that you are fine with a global setting in `DiffMinChange` and `DiffMaxChange`. Then apply denormalization inside your cost function.

Comment: Yes, exactly if I use  `DiffMinChange` and `DiffMaxChange `optimized for the first parameter, it is applied also for the other parameter inside the vector.
I didn't think to normalize everything. I can use this solution. I will wait for some other answers (if arrive) before set "answered" in case there exist some other functions that can do the work, but your solution is perfect for the problem.